# Problem with subdomain with multisite

Tags: multisite, subdomains

I am importing a wordpress multisite of my client (i don't create this site) and is a wordpress multisite. the main site is working perfectly but the subdomain is not working and it comes out "The requested URL /wp-admin was not found on this server."
I already change DNS of my hosting.

Does anyone have a solution for the problem?

[image]

Comment: Have you set up the [`.htaccess` file](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/htaccess/) for WordPress Multisite (see the Subdomain example)?